# WXR slicing script

Tags: import, scripts, bulk-import

I have a massive WXR file im trying to import into wordpress. I run out of memory when i try to import as one file, so I'm thinking of how i can split the big file into smaller files programatically and if anyone had a script to do this

Comment: For reference: Tyler [asked this on the `wp-hackers` mailing list too](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/wp-hackers/kcnuZhSOi24/discussion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling for "split wxr file" returned several results, including

- [python script for splitting .wxr file](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wxr-file-splitter#post-1859415)
- [GUI for splitting WXR files](http://mvmanila.com/2008/09/21/split-wxr-with-gui-and-installers/) (OSX and Windows)
- [.Net splitter for WXR files](http://www.rangerpretzel.com/content/view/20/1/)

Haven't tried any of these, but the comments look positive.

Comment: Your link to the ".Net Splitter for WXR files" was swiped wholesale from my site. I've read this person's blog a bit and he seems to have a bad habit of stealing other people's posts and putting them on his site as his own. It would be one thing if he was quoting and linking to my site, but he's currently hosting an old (and buggy) version of my WXR Splitter (v. 1.0). The latest version is currently 1.51 as of this writing. I would prefer if you didn't link to him. thanks.

Comment: @pretzel - I've changed the link to point to your site.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [WXR Splitter for Windows (.NET)](http://www.rangerpretzel.com/content/view/20/1/) - it gets approx. 10 downloads per day. People generally like it.

Comment: You have a spam problem on your blog :-)